# is it possible to add records to a result set after Order By in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

This sounds like a stupid question while I'm asking it, but I'm new to SQL and not sure if something like this is possible.

I want to select all records from a table except for 2, order them alphabetically and then append the last two to the end. Can I do this in a select statement or do I have to create a temp table and returned a result set from that?

Basically, in pseudo-code, I want to do this:

```
select
  firstname,
  lastname, 
  otherdata
  from People
    where firstname != 'john' or 'mark'
      order by firstname
  add John and Mark
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to use a `UNION` to combine queries and `ORDER BY` must come last. e.g.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, otherdata
 FROM dbo.People
 WHERE firstname NOT IN ('john', 'mark')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', NULL, NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Mark', NULL, NULL
ORDER BY firstname;
```

If your intention is to place those two rows last, then you need something else to order by, e.g.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, otherdata, z = 1
 FROM dbo.People
 WHERE firstname NOT IN ('john', 'mark')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', NULL, NULL, z = 2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Mark', NULL, NULL, z = 3
ORDER BY z, firstname;
```

You might see cute tricks where people will put the query in a subquery and apply an order by there (with the help of `TOP`), but beware, this is a ruse! This will not guarantee how the outer query is ordered.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. The way the table is set up, there's nothing else to order on that would work. Looks like it's temp table weather. =)

Comment: Can you explain why you need a temp table? My query applied ordering without something in the table to dictate it.

Comment: I misunderstood what the z did. So it assigns z = 1 to every record but john and mark and then gives them 2 and 3 to order them at the end? I get it now. Very clever, Aaron. Very clever, indeed. Thanks again, man.